# Cakephp 2 using EXISTS inside Conditions array

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakePHP 2.5.2, and i need to use exists clause inside the conditions array.

This is what i am trying :

```
$paginate['conditions'][] = Array('exists ("SELECT 1 FROM jobs j JOIN company c ON c.id = j.company_id")');
```

I am getting the "identifier too long message" and no result is generated.

The query generated is :

```
AND exists ("SELECT 1 FROM jobs j JOIN company c ON c.id = j.company_id")
```

How can i use exists inside the conditions array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the MySql EXISTS function, then the problem is with your quotes.  Try changing:

```
$paginate['conditions'][] = Array(
    'exists ("SELECT 1 FROM jobs j JOIN company c ON c.id = j.company_id")'
);
```

to

```
$paginate['conditions'][] = Array(
    "exists (SELECT 1 FROM jobs j JOIN company c ON c.id = j.company_id)"
);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it works, can i create or have access to an variable using beforeFind or afterFind to use inside the exists subquery ? i need the company id to use into a WHERE c.id = $companyId

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, then yeah you can append info to the `$results` array in your afterFind.  So if you create a variable `$companyId` in the afterFind, add something like `$results['company_id'] = $companyId` and return `$results`.

Comment: i need into afterFind generate an array so into the controller i can use it on paginate conditions into the controller. If try into the before find but could not use a loop an arrays.

Comment: what is the syntax to get a variable from afterFind into the controller?